# Preferences regarding contract/permanent positions not honored

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

My preferences are set to only be interested in contract work, yet I only get suggested to companies looking only for permanent employees.

Comment: where are you getting those suggestions? could you paste a screenshot please? thanks!

Comment: companies get me as a suggestion when looking for permanent employees and keep contacting me because of it.

Comment: thanks for your report! we have identified the place where we weren't using the contract bit to filter candidates, and will work on this.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the suggestion. We've added a filter to the recommender which respects your job search preferences. So if you said you're not interested in full-time work, you should not get recommended to employers for full-time jobs.

Apologies for the delay in getting this done, it required an unusually large amount of coordination across various teams.

Comment: Still within 6 to 8 weeks. You're good ...

Comment: I am very happy that you took care of this issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: It looks as this filter isn't working anymore. I am getting a lot of offers for permanent positions again.

Comment: @AnnaMelzer Thanks for getting back in touch. Looks like the last few recruiters to message you found your profile through our Candidate Search feature, not through the recommender. Candidate Search does allow recruiters to filter for people looking for permanent or contract work but unfortunately we can't _force_ people to use the filter because our new mind-control feature isn't out of beta yet . My advice is to just hit the "not interested" button

Comment: Will do, thanks for looking into that again! :)

Comment: Would be nice to also have this as a filter option when searching for jobs. Without it the search is pointless for any dev looking only for contract positions.